# AndroidPublisherService - Play Developer API Client - Upload aab failes due to bad credentials

Tags: c#, .net, google-play-services, service-accounts

Trying to make use of the AndroidPublisherService from Play Developer API Client.
I can list active tracks and the releases in those tracks, but when I try to upload a new build there seems to be no way of attaching the authentication already made previously to read data.

I've authenticated using `var googleCredentials = GoogleCredential.FromStream(keyDataStream) .CreateWithUser(serviceUsername);` where serviceUsername is the email for my service account.

```
    private static void Execute(string packageName, string aabfile, string credfile, string serviceUsername)
    {
        var credentialsFilename = credfile;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(credentialsFilename))
        {
            // Check env. var
            credentialsFilename =
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS",
                    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Using credentials {credfile} with package {packageName} for aab file {aabfile}");
        
        var keyDataStream = File.OpenRead(credentialsFilename);
        var googleCredentials = GoogleCredential.FromStream(keyDataStream)
            .CreateWithUser(serviceUsername);
        var credentials = googleCredentials.UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
        
        var service = new AndroidPublisherService();
        
        var edit = service.Edits.Insert(new AppEdit { ExpiryTimeSeconds = "3600" }, packageName);
        edit.Credential = credentials;
        var activeEditSession = edit.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine($"Edits started with id {activeEditSession.Id}");
        
        var tracksList = service.Edits.Tracks.List(packageName, activeEditSession.Id);
        tracksList.Credential = credentials;
        var tracksResponse = tracksList.Execute();
        foreach (var track in tracksResponse.Tracks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Track: {track.TrackValue}");
            Console.WriteLine("Releases: ");
            foreach (var rel in track.Releases)
                Console.WriteLine($"{rel.Name} version: {rel.VersionCodes.FirstOrDefault()} - Status: {rel.Status}");
        }
        
        using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(aabfile);
        var upload = service.Edits.Bundles.Upload(packageName, activeEditSession.Id, fileStream, "application/octet-stream");
        var uploadProgress = upload.Upload();
        if (uploadProgress == null || uploadProgress.Exception != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to upload. Error: {uploadProgress?.Exception}");
            return;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Upload {uploadProgress.Status}");

        var tracksUpdate = service.Edits.Tracks.Update(new Track
        {
            Releases = new List<TrackRelease>(new[]
            {
                new TrackRelease
                {
                    Name = "Roswell - Grenis Dev Test",
                    Status = "completed",
                    VersionCodes = new List<long?>(new[] {(long?) upload?.ResponseBody?.VersionCode})
                }
            })
        }, packageName, activeEditSession.Id, "internal");
        
        tracksUpdate.Credential = credentials;
        var trackResult = tracksUpdate.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine($"Track {trackResult?.TrackValue}");

        var commitResult = service.Edits.Commit(packageName, activeEditSession.Id);
        Console.WriteLine($"{commitResult.EditId} has been committed");
    }
```

And as the code points out, all action objects such as `tracksList.Credential = credentials;` can be given the credentials generated from the service account.

*BUT* the actual upload action `var upload = service.Edits.Bundles.Upload(packageName, activeEditSession.Id, fileStream, "application/octet-stream");` does not expose a `.Credential` object, and it always fails with:

```
    The service androidpublisher has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [401]
Errors [
        Message[Login Required.] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[required] Domain[global]
]

   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.InitiateSessionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload.UploadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

So, how would I go about providing the actual Upload action with the given credentials here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to figure this out during the day, I was missing one call to `CreateScoped()` when creating the `GoogleCredential` object as well as a call to `InitiateSession()` on the upload object.

```
            var googleCredentials = GoogleCredential.FromStream(keyDataStream)
                .CreateWithUser(serviceUsername)
                .CreateScoped(AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher);
```

Once that was done I could then get a valid oauth token by calling

```
            var googleCredentials = GoogleCredential.FromStream(keyDataStream)
                .CreateWithUser(serviceUsername)
                .CreateScoped(AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher);
            
            var credentials = googleCredentials.UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
            var oauthToken = credentials?.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher).Result;
```

And I can now use that oauth token in the upload request:

```
            upload.OauthToken = oauthToken;
            _ = await upload.InitiateSessionAsync();
            
            var uploadProgress = await upload.UploadAsync();
            if (uploadProgress == null || uploadProgress.Exception != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to upload. Error: {uploadProgress?.Exception}");
                return;
            }
```

The full code example for successfully uploading a new aab file to google play store internal test track thus looks something like this:

```
        private async Task UploadGooglePlayRelease(string fileToUpload, string changeLogFile, string serviceUsername, string packageName)
        {
            var serviceAccountFile = ResolveServiceAccountCertificateInfoFile();
            if (!serviceAccountFile.Exists)
                throw new ApplicationException($"Failed to find the service account certificate file. {serviceAccountFile.FullName}");
            
            var keyDataStream = File.OpenRead(serviceAccountFile.FullName);
            var googleCredentials = GoogleCredential.FromStream(keyDataStream)
                .CreateWithUser(serviceUsername)
                .CreateScoped(AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher);
            
            var credentials = googleCredentials.UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
            var oauthToken = credentials?.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher).Result;
            
            var service = new AndroidPublisherService();
            
            var edit = service.Edits.Insert(new AppEdit { ExpiryTimeSeconds = "3600" }, packageName);
            edit.Credential = credentials;
            var activeEditSession = await edit.ExecuteAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation($"Edits started with id {activeEditSession.Id}");
            
            var tracksList = service.Edits.Tracks.List(packageName, activeEditSession.Id);
            tracksList.Credential = credentials;
            var tracksResponse = await tracksList.ExecuteAsync();
            foreach (var track in tracksResponse.Tracks)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Track: {track.TrackValue}");
                _logger.LogInformation("Releases: ");
                foreach (var rel in track.Releases)
                    _logger.LogInformation($"{rel.Name} version: {rel.VersionCodes.FirstOrDefault()} - Status: {rel.Status}");
            }

            var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);
            var upload = service.Edits.Bundles.Upload(packageName, activeEditSession.Id, fileStream, "application/octet-stream");
            
            upload.OauthToken = oauthToken;
            _ = await upload.InitiateSessionAsync();
            
            var uploadProgress = await upload.UploadAsync();
            if (uploadProgress == null || uploadProgress.Exception != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to upload. Error: {uploadProgress?.Exception}");
                return;
            }
            
            _logger.LogInformation($"Upload {uploadProgress.Status}");

            var releaseNotes = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(changeLogFile);

            var tracksUpdate = service.Edits.Tracks.Update(new Track
            {
                Releases = new List<TrackRelease>(new[]
                {
                    new TrackRelease
                    {
                        Name = $"{upload?.ResponseBody?.VersionCode}",
                        Status = "completed",
                        InAppUpdatePriority = 5,
                        CountryTargeting = new CountryTargeting { IncludeRestOfWorld = true },
                        ReleaseNotes = new List<LocalizedText>(new []{ new LocalizedText {  Language = "en-US", Text = releaseNotes } }),
                        VersionCodes = new List<long?>(new[] {(long?) upload?.ResponseBody?.VersionCode})
                    }
                })
            }, packageName, activeEditSession.Id, "internal");
            
            tracksUpdate.Credential = credentials;
            var trackResult = await tracksUpdate.ExecuteAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation($"Track {trackResult?.TrackValue}");

            var commitResult = service.Edits.Commit(packageName, activeEditSession.Id);
            commitResult.Credential = credentials;
            await commitResult.ExecuteAsync();
            
            _logger.LogInformation($"{commitResult.EditId} has been committed");
        }
```

Comment: I get a forbidden error. Does this require the app to already exist as a published one in Google play? The credentials I'm using have "owner" role, so not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: A bit late to reply, but yes, one needs to manually upload the first time before it starts working. I have no clue to why that is, just some google thing I suppose.